Build PHP for DirectAdmin using custombuild from alternative sources
I wanted to build php82 for DirectAdmin using Custombuild and got the result:
PHP 7.4.30 Installed.
Downloading             php-8.2.0RC1.tar.gz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Download of http://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.2.0RC1.tar.gz failed, re-downloading the file...
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Download of http://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.2.0RC1.tar.gz failed, re-downloading the file...
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Download of http://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.2.0RC1.tar.gz failed, re-downloading the file...
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Download of http://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.2.0RC1.tar.gz failed, re-downloading the file...
Download of http://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.2.0RC1.tar.gz failed 4 times, exiting...

Everyone can see that php74 has been built successfully but not php82.
DA version and Custombuild version:
# custombuild/build version
2.0.0 (rev: 2945)
# ./directadmin version
Version: DirectAdmin v.1.60.4

http://files.directadmin.com/services/custombuild/php-8.2.0RC1.tar.gz is 404 now, so:

Can I use alternative sources and what are they?
Can I just download PHP from https://www.php.net/downloads.php, put it in custombuild directory then run ./build php n again?
Is there any other approach?

Please help. Thank you so much.

Because I couldn't find any alternative sources so I decided to try the approach 2:


Can I just download PHP from https://www.php.net/downloads.php, put it in custombuild directory then run ./build php n again?


The answer is "yes". But it needs a little trick.
The main idea: specify exactly which PHP version that custombuild should build and make it finds PHP file on local.
# echo "127.0.0.1 files.directadmin.com" >> /etc/hosts
# mkdir -p /var/www/html/services/custombuild
# cd /var/www/html/services/custombuild
# wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.2.18.tar.gz
# chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/services
# cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
# sed -i 's/^php82/php82:8.2.18:[GPG_key]/' version.txt
# ./build set php2_mode php-fpm
# ./build set php2_release 8.2
# ./build php_expert 8.2 php-fpm

Can get GPG_key at https://www.php.net/downloads.php

php-8.2.18.tar.gz
b934ca7e8c82945c5cbf0aa2a3f66727eb5b5098e551819e1b090572d6a51ead

